# Finding particular solution for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$(p^2+q^2)x=pz, p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
For the above PDE, I need to find the solution that passes through $x=0, z^2=4y$

I used Charpit's method to get complete solution as $$z^2=a^2x^2+(ay+b)^2$$

To find the particular solution, I substitute $x=0, z^2=4y$ here to get $$a^2y^2+(2ab-4)y+b^2=0.$$

But I do not know how to proceed from here. Can somebody help?

Comment: This isn't a PDE... there are no partial derivatives anywhere.

Comment: @LordVader007 we use $p, q$ to denote partial derivatives; I was under the impression that that was standard notation. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: If your complete solution is correct, then there is no such solution, as $(ay+b)^2 \not\equiv 4y$ for any $a,b$.

Comment: @AlexJones can you comment on the method posted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to start off by saying that I don't understand how and why this method works, I am picking it from a MD Raisinghania, a standard book for PDE. If anybody can explain the intuition, that would be very helpful.

The complete solution is $f:z^2=a^2x^2+(ay+b)^2$

Substituting $x=0, z^2=4y$ into $f$, we get
$$g:a^2y^2+(2ab-4)y+b^2=0$$

$g$ is an equation with $y$ as parameter. So we eliminate $y$ from $g=0$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ (like finding an envelop).

This gives us $ab=1$.

Substituting $b=1/a$ in complete solution $f$, we get

$f_2:z^2-a^2x^2-(ay+\frac 1 a)^2=0$

We now find envelop of $f_2=0$ with $a$ as parameter, ie eliminate $a$ from $f_2=0$ and $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}=0$. This gives us, $$(z^2-2y)^2=4(x^2+y^2)$$

This is the required solution that passes through given curve.